# How to resolve getting wrong compiled output NodeJS and Babel

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I am having a problem here so I am building a NodeJS controller I have installed `@babel/prese-env @babel/core @babel/cli`...

The problem that I am facing is when I compile the code using babel running the following script: `"build": "mkdir dist && babel src -s -d dist"` the script works **but** when I try to test the compiled version to see if it works as expected I get unexpected behaviour...

So the controller is built using **Classes** so I expected the following behavior below:

1. When I make a new instance of the class object of the bet VSCode should prompt of the parameters that I have to pass on for the class constructor **(I know this might not be a clear indication of broken code cause VSCode could be lagging)**.
2. When I try to access the methods within the class I am unable to access those methods **(Now this is more clear indication of broken code)**

**Code Snippet of the controller: (I will link my Github so you can see full version but with ths snippet the error should be reproducible)**

```
class ExpressSessionAuth {
  constructor(
    userModel,
    userSessions,
    mailTransporterUser,
    mailTransporterPass,
    passwordLength,
    hashRounds
  ) {
    this.userModel = userModel;
    this.mailTransporterUser = mailTransporterUser;
    this.mailTransporterPass = mailTransporterPass;
    this.passwordLength = passwordLength || 8;
    this.hashRounds = hashRounds || 15;
    this.userSessions = userSessions;
  }

  SignUp(request, response) {
    const form = new Formidable.IncomingForm();

    try {
      form.parse(request, async (error, fields, files) => {
        if (error) {
          return response
            .status(500)
            .json({ msg: "Network Error: Failed to signup user" });
        }

        const { username, email, password, verifiedPassword } = fields;

        if (!username || !email || !password || !verifiedPassword) {
          return response.status(500).json({ msg: "All fields are required" });
        }

        if (password.trim().length < this.passwordLength) {
          return response
            .status(400)
            .json({ msg: "Password has to be at least 8 characters" });
        }

        if (password.trim() !== verifiedPassword.trim()) {
          return response.status(400).json({ msg: "Password's do not match" });
        }

        const isUserAlreadyExising = await this.userModel.findOne({
          email: email,
        });

        if (isUserAlreadyExising) {
          return response
            .status(400)
            .json({ msg: "Account with this email already exist" });
        }

        const salt = await Bcrypt.genSalt(this.hashRounds);
        const hashedPassword = await Bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
        const newUser = new this.userModel({
          email: email,
          username: username,
          password: hashedPassword,
        });

        const savedUser = await newUser.save();

        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          service: "SendinBlue",
          auth: {
            user: this.mailTransporterUser,
            pass: this.mailTransporterPass,
          },
        });
}

export default ExpressSessionAuth
```

**Below is code index.js entry point where I import the controller then export so**

```
import ExpressSessionAuth from "./Auth";

export default ExpressSessionAuth;
```

**Below is where I tried to test the compiled version of everything and this is where I failed to access the full potential of the class controller**

```
const expressSession = require("./dist/index");

const exp = new expressSession();
```

**Below I will provide link to full source code but with just this code snippets above the error should be reproducible:**
[Link to source code](https://github.com/Ntshembo-Hlongwane1/express-session-auth)

Comment: Have you tried `const exp = new expressSession.default();` If you log `expressSession` what do you get?

Comment: Okay I just tried that which you said and seems to work out when I run test's, but can you clear me on this why is that when then instance of the class is made it does not show the parameter's needed by the constructor, that would be really useful when using this package plan is to have this on npm to improve my workflow tired of writing same auth logic :D